# Is a Spring DriverManagerDataSource password stored in plaintext?

Tags: spring, encryption, passwords

You can set a `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` user name and password with:

```
dataSource.setUsername("johnsmith");
dataSource.setPassword("myplaintextpassword");
```

My question is - if I were to create an object this way, and then examine the memory of the machine this is running on, could I see the plaintext password?

If so, how can one securely create a database connection using a passed in password?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Create a complete heapdump of the process or JVM and you will be able to see it.

I don't know what operating system your application runs in or if it is standalone or run in container like Tomcat but exactly this is the reason why processes need to be separated.
You have to make sure that the file or JNDI configuration your password is stored in is only accessible by those processes / users that absolutely need access to them. And an additional layer of encryption will help too. There always will be someone (like root on Linux) who can read every process memory but your job is to keep the group of people being able to do this as small as possible.

Perhaps serverfault is a better place for asking or searching details about this. I am sure you can describe your environment (OS, container for your application, ...), try to get help for that setup.

Comment: I've added a part to the question to ask how you could secure the password.